# Pandas left outer join multiple dataframes on multiple columns

Tags: python, sql, merge, pandas

I am new to using DataFrame and I would like to know how to perform a SQL equivalent of left outer join on multiple columns on a series of tables

Example:

```
df1: 
Year    Week    Colour    Val1 
2014       A       Red      50
2014       B       Red      60
2014       B     Black      70
2014       C       Red      10
2014       D     Green      20

df2:
Year    Week    Colour    Val2
2014       A     Black      30
2014       B     Black     100
2014       C     Green      50
2014       C       Red      20
2014       D       Red      40

df3:
Year    Week    Colour    Val3
2013       B       Red      60
2013       C     Black      80
2013       B     Black      10
2013       D     Green      20
2013       D       Red      50
```

Essentially I want to do something like this SQL code (Notice that df3 is not joined on Year):

```
SELECT df1.*, df2.Val2, df3.Val3
FROM df1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN df2
    ON df1.Year = df2.Year
    AND df1.Week = df2.Week
    AND df1.Colour = df2.Colour
  LEFT OUTER JOIN df3
    ON df1.Week = df3.Week
    AND df1.Colour = df3.Colour
```

The result should look like:

```
Year    Week    Colour    Val1    Val2    Val3
2014       A       Red      50    Null    Null
2014       B       Red      60    Null      60
2014       B     Black      70     100    Null
2014       C       Red      10      20    Null
2014       D     Green      20    Null    Null
```

I have tried using merge and join but can't figure out how to do it on multiple tables and when there are multiple joints involved. Could someone help me on this please?

Thanks

Comment: For more information on various facets and functionality of the merge, join, and concat API, please take a look at [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Merge them in two steps, `df1` and `df2` first, and then the result of that to `df3`.

```
In [33]: s1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Year', 'Week', 'Colour'])
```

I dropped year from df3 since you don't need it for the last join.

```
In [39]: df = pd.merge(s1, df3[['Week', 'Colour', 'Val3']],
                       how='left', on=['Week', 'Colour'])

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
   Year Week Colour  Val1  Val2 Val3
0  2014    A    Red    50   NaN  NaN
1  2014    B    Red    60   NaN   60
2  2014    B  Black    70   100   10
3  2014    C    Red    10    20  NaN
4  2014    D  Green    20   NaN   20

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As I have quite a few dataframes, I was looking for a quick way of joining the tables all together in one step - similar to using 'join' as you can join more than two tables in one step. However, I can't figure out how to do it on multiple join conditions. If there's no quicker way of doing this, I'll just stick to what you suggested :)

Comment: pandas join is more relational algebra than relational calculus, you need to specify the steps in order. SQL allows you to specify everything together, and the query engine decides the best steps to produce the result.

Answer (score 18):

One can also do this with a compact version of @TomAugspurger's answer, like so:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Year', 'Week', 'Colour']).merge(df3[['Week', 'Colour', 'Val3']], how='left', on=['Week', 'Colour'])
```