# Pandas merge DataFrames based on index/column combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two [DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) that I want to [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge). I have read about [merging on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786490/pandas-left-outer-join-multiple-dataframes-on-multiple-columns), and [preserving the index when merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge). My problem needs to cater for both, and I am having difficulty figuring out the best way to do this.

The first DataFrame looks like this

[image]

and the second looks like this

[image]

I want to merge these based on the `Date` **and** the `ID`. In the first DataFrame the `Date` is the index and the `ID` is a column; in the second DataFrame both `Date` and `ID` are part of a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

Essentially, as a result I want a DataFrame that looks like DataFrame 2 with an additional column for the `Events` from DataFrame 1.

Comment: Mind posting the text for the DataFrames so we don't have to recreate them by hand?

Comment: They are created by reading from MongoDB, and I can't share that data unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reseting the index (`reset_index`) and then merging the DataFrame, as you've read.  Then you can set the index (`set_index`) to reproduce your desired MultiIndex.