# How to Join / Merge datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Dataframes `DF1` and `DF2`. My goal is to look up `DF2` with `DF1` columns as
keys; and save the returns as outcomes in `DF3`. Can someone help me with getting
`DF3`?

e.g.

```
DF1                         DF2
map test1   test2           No.     outcome
A   NaN     NaN             1       AA
B   NaN     5               2       BB
C   1       6               3       CC
D   2       7               4       DD
E   3       NaN             5       EE
F   4       NaN             6       FF
G   5       8               7       GG
H   6       9               8       HH
I   7       10              9       II
                            10      JJ
                            11      KK
                            12      LL
                            13      MM

DF3
map test1   test2   outcome1        outcome2
A   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN
B   NaN     5       NaN             EE
C   1       6       AA              FF
D   2       7       BB              GG
E   3       NaN     CC              NaN
F   4       NaN     DD              NaN
G   5       8       EE              HH
H   6       9       FF              II
I   7       10      GG              JJ
```

I am currently using two join functions, but this is not what I need. It drops `NaN`s in `DF1`, and only returns the overlap of `test1` and `test2`.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on='test1', right_on='No.')
df3 = df3.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on='test2', right_on='No.')
```

currently my code will return this:

DF3
map test1   test2   outcome1    outcome2
C   1   6   AA  FF
D   2   7   BB  GG
G   5   8   EE  HH
H   6   9   FF  II
I   7   10  GG  JJ

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2RoV.png

Comment: What's a "dataset" (because that's not the name of any built-in Python datatype)?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I meant pandas dataframes

Comment: what's wrong with using two statements to achieve this?

Comment: Dataframes aren't something built-in either. I've updated the tags for your question accordingly.

Comment: You need 2 outer left joins, already discussed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786490/pandas-left-outer-join-multiple-dataframes-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map would be more efficient in this case

```
DF3 = DF1.copy()
DF3['outcome1'] = DF1['test1'].map(DF2.set_index('No.')['outcome'])
DF3['outcome2'] = DF1['test2'].map(DF2.set_index('No.')['outcome'])

    map test1   test2   outcome1    outcome2
0   A   NaN     NaN     NaN         NaN
1   B   NaN     5.0     NaN         EE
2   C   1.0     6.0     AA          FF
3   D   2.0     7.0     BB          GG
4   E   3.0     NaN     CC          NaN
5   F   4.0     NaN     DD          NaN
6   G   5.0     8.0     EE          HH
7   H   6.0     9.0     FF          II
8   I   7.0     10.0    GG          JJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you like code golf?

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_on='test1',right_on='No.'),df2, how='left',left_on='test2',right_on='No.').drop(['No._x','No._y'], axis=1).rename(columns={'outcome_x':'outcome1','outcome_y':'outcome2'})

  map  test1  test2 outcome1 outcome2
0   A    NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
1   B    NaN    5.0      NaN       EE
2   C    1.0    6.0       AA       FF
3   D    2.0    7.0       BB       GG
4   E    3.0    NaN       CC      NaN
5   F    4.0    NaN       DD      NaN
6   G    5.0    8.0       EE       HH
7   H    6.0    9.0       FF       II
8   I    7.0   10.0       GG       JJ
```

Comment: Sou ka, this is great. So in essence, I used how = 'inner' for my merge, but should have used how = 'left'.